# How to partially rollback?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I currently populate a database from a third party API that involves downloading files containing multiple SQL `INSERT`/`DELETE`/`UPDATE` statements and then parsing them into SQLAlchemy ORM objects to load into my database.

These files can often contain errors that I've tried to build in some integrity checks for. The particular one I'm currently struggling with is duplicate records - basically receiving a file to insert a record that currently exists. To avoid this I put a unique index on the fields that form a composite primary key. However, this means I get an error when processing a file with an SQL statement that tries to duplicate a record and a `flush` or `commit` is subsequently issued.

I don't want to commit records to the database until all the SQL statements for a given file have been processed so I can keep track of what's been processed. I was thinking that I could issue a `flush` at the end of the processing of every statement and then have some error handling if it fails because of a duplicate record. This would include bypassing the offending statement. However, as I understand the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#rolling-back) then issuing a `rollback` would cancel all the previous statements that had been processed to that point when I only want to skip the duplicate one.

Is there an option to partially rollback in some way or do I need to build a check up front that queries the database to check if executing an SQL statement will create a duplicate record?

Comment: The ability to use nested transactions / savepoints depends on the underlying database server (and very few of them support it).  You're probably better off reading before writing to check for duplicate keys. Most databases have a transaction isolation mode that will let you access data from the current transaction that has not yet been committed.

Comment: Looks like `SAVEPOINT` is ok for MySQL 8.0 so thanks for the tip! Now just trying to work out how to implement `begin_nested()` into the loop that processes each statement. Would you know if it's possible to overwrite the `nested` object in the example here - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint. Or should I create a new object on each loop and store them in a list to selectively rollback from?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was a general statement on SQL databases, I've never actually used SQLAlchemy (which is why I didn't post an answer)